# To call hook on a php external file

Tags: php, wp-load.php

I can't  to call the a filter hook on a php external file of wordpress.

This is my code - my_external_file.php -:

```
<?php
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../../../../../wp-load.php');

add_filter('init', 'test_function');

function test_function (){
    global $global_text_to_shown;

    $global_text_to_shown = 'Hello World';

}

global $global_text_to_shown;

$quicktags_settings = array( 'buttons' => 'strong,em,link,block,del,ins,img,ul,ol,li,code,spell,close' );

//This work fine, shown editor good.
wp_editor( $global_text_to_show, 'content', array( 'media_buttons' => false, 'tinymce' => true, 'quicktags' => $quicktags_settings ) );

//Load js and work fine the editor - wp_editor function.
wp_footer();

?>
```

The problem is that not load or  execute the filter hook and 'test_function' function, can't take value: `$global_text_to_shown = 'Hello World';`

How i can execute hook on external **PHP** file?

Comment: This **PHP** file is call: http://localhost/wp352/wp-content/plugins/test/theme/widgets/rich-text/templates/builder-options-rte.php?text_content=

Comment: I am pretty sure that `wp-load.php` will run the `init` hook before your function gets attached. But please explain what you are doing and why. There may be a better way to do this.

Comment: @s_ha_dum: I need call a hook filter in this php file. The wp_editor, html specifics, not send submit data and i need add this hook `add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'update_rte');` this function work fine when i doing on post/page. Can help me now? You need more description about?

Comment: That doesn't tell me what you are doing or why. What is the point? What is the end goal? I suspect you may have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).